# Rxjs with big abject element array back-end loop with observable

Tags: javascript, arrays, rxjs, observable

I created simple number array and use rxjs to manage UI and the backend loop the following is my code :

```
var array100 = new Array(9703)
  .fill('x')
  .map((v, i) => i);

 Rx.Observable.from(array100)
  .delayWhen(function(v){return Rx.Observable.timer(v*50)})
  .buffer(Rx.Observable.timer(250, 250))
  .subscribe(chunk => {
    console.log('chunk ', chunk);
  });
```

after creating this sample application I tried to took this to my aplication with some big abject element array to handle the UI and the backend loop. but when I trying to use it the array can be observble but it is not chunking the array. it pass the method without chunking. I cannot debug it also ..

How is this achieved in RxJS?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have a good look at the supplied operators. A lot of the functionality you are trying to create is available already.

For delaying emission of elements from your array you can use:
`.flatMap(val => Rx.Observable.just(val).delay(50)/*ms*/)`

For chunking your array you can use count (if timing is not an issue) `.bufferWithCount(50)/*elements per chunk */`, timing `.bufferWithTime(250/*ms*/)` or both combined (`.bufferWithTimeOrCount(250 /*ms*/, 50 /*elements */)`